# Hints about how to prove that a nonempty finite subset of R has a maximum element without using mathematical induction

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to show that every finite nonempty subset of real numbers has a maximum element without using mathematical induction. I started by assuming that if the given set is finite, then it is bounded so it has a maximum element. But I don't really rely on this conclusion. I just want some hints (not answers) in order to continue my proof.

Comment: Is contradiction works for you? You can assume there is no maximum element: start by any element since non-empty, and then generate more than finite elements by using the assumption.

Comment: How do you define finite?

Comment: @Andres: Good call! I'd missed the recursion step in my mental proof outline, so that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\mathbb{R}$ is ordered field, the elements of any set can be expressed in increasing or decreasing order. Since the set is finite, this process must terminate somewhere. Then the first and the last elements are the maximum and minimum elements in the set.

Another approach: Let the set be $S=\{a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_k \}$.Construct an increasing sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ using the elements of $S$.Then since $S$ is finite(and hence bounded),by Bolzano-Weierstrass property,$(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges(eventually constant)to a point $x \in S$.Clearly $x$ is the maximum element of $S$.

Comment: This is an induction argument.